# Making like button event independent for each element with unlike functionality, using Angular

Tags: angular

I wish to create a Like button that will increase the counter onClick, and decrease the counter on another click. 
Since I have a bunch of elements with the like button, I wish them to act separately from each other. Please notice, I'm using a button on the fetched element.

here is my template:

```
<h1>Liked albums: {{ likesCounter }}</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="album-grid">
    <div *ngFor="let album of albums">
      <div
        class="album"        
      >
        <div class="text">
          <h4>{{ album.name }},</h4>
          <button (click)="buttonHandler()">
            <i [className]="isClicked ? 'fas fa-heart' : 'far fa-heart'"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`{{ likesCounter }}` is the counter I would like to update.

`ButtonHandler()` is changing the `{{ likeCounter }}` value, and changing the style of the icon, when it's cliked.
Here is the .ts code:

```
likesCounter: number = 0;

isClicked: boolean = false;

  buttonHandler = () => {
     this.likesCounter += 1
    this.isClicked = true;
   
  };
```

In general, 2 things I want to do here is:

1. Unlike the album if the same button was clicked twice.
2. Make albums act separate from each other

Link to the repo: https://github.com/paslavskyi9roman/Spotilar/tree/dev

Comment: is `likesCounter` meant to be separate for each album, or is it the total sum of like for all albums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want each album to be either liked or not liked, add a boolean property to the album definition, e.g:

```
export interface album {
//other fields
liked: boolean;
}
```

Then pass the album as a param to the button click function:

```
<button (click)="buttonHandler(album)">
```

And in component ts, switch the liked property value of the passed in album, based on if it is currently true or false. The counter can also be updated here to store the total of liked albums by using the filtered array length :

```
buttonHandler(album: album) {
    album.liked = !album.liked;
    this.likesCounter = this.albums.filter(a => a.liked).length;
  }
```

The counter can display in the html as a total of albums with liked = true:

[Simple Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fceajy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: thank you for the answer with an example. It's work for me!

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this would be to add another property to the `album` indicating if it has been liked or not (`isLiked`), then:

- have `buttonHandler` simply toggle this property on each click
- instead of using `likesCounter`, you could use a getter that calculate

```
buttonHandler = (album: Album) => {
   album.isLiked = !album.isLiked;
};

get totalLikes() {
  return this.albums.filter(a => a.isLiked).length;
}
```